# SQL to make the final result display all data (matching and not matching) from both table after joining the two table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table which storing Students data

Table A

| Name | id | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 | Marketing |
| Dom | 2 | Science |
| Edward | 3 | IT |

Table B

| Name | id | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dom | 2 | Mathematic |
| Chris | 4 | IT |

Now I plan to display all student data as below

| Name | id | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 | Marketing |
| Dom | 2 | Science, Mathematic |
| Edward | 3 | IT |
| Chris | 4 | IT |

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN a.name = b.name THEN a.name ELSE a.name AS Student_Name,
    CASE WHEN a.id = b.id THEN a.id ELSE a.id AS Student_Id,
    CASE WHEN a.course = b.course THEN a.course + ',' + b.course ELSE a.course AS Student_Course
FROM student a
FULL JOIN student b ON a.name=b.name
```

But with above query I only able to get the result as

| Name | id | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 | Marketing |
| Dom | 2 | Science, Mathematic |
| Edward | 3 | IT |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Which Chris become NULL in final result...How can I make it to select all? Have suffer on this whole week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take a union of the two tables and then aggregate by name:

```sql
SELECT name, id, GROUP_CONCAT(course) AS courses  -- see note below
FROM
(
    SELECT name, id, course FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, id, course FROM TableB
) t
GROUP BY name, id
ORDER BY id;
```

Note that the above would be for MySQL.  If you're really using SQL Server (2016 or later), then replace `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `STRING_AGG()`.

Comment: Thanks master!! you solve my problem!! it is work for me using STRING_AGG(). Really appreciate